# aws each person needs to create new key pair to access EC2?

Tags: amazon-web-services

someone in my team has created key pair to access EC2 instance. I realize I am not able to download the existing key pair. Does it mean each team member has to create a new key pair to access EC2? Thanks

Answer (score 4):

This is a strategy that we use regularly on our bastion hosts. To achieve this, we actually store each users SSH Public Keys in their IAM users, then look up the connecting user at connect time, and get their public keys, based on an authorized IAM group.

I've open sourced this functionality and it can be round in the Github [IAM SSH](https://github.com/Giftbit/iam-ssh) repo.

To do this, The instance checks it's tags for an `AuthorizedUsersGroup`. Based on this tag, it checks for an authorized user, and retrieves their SSH Public keys.

Of note here, it uses the following policy:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "iam:GetGroup",
        "iam:GetSSHPublicKey",
        "iam:ListSSHPublicKeys"
      ],
      "Resource": [
        "*"
      ]
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "ec2:DescribeTags"
      ],
      "Resource": [
        "*"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Other benefits of this strategy, if someone leaves the company, or for some other reason needs to access removed to the instance, you can remove them from the AuthorizedUsersGroup.

Answer (score 3):

Share private keys just as you would share passwords. That is to say, never.

Answer (score 3):

EC2 Key pairs can be downloaded only once from AWS Console. You may share copies of it with each team member. Amazon will not keep a copy of the private key, once lost it cannot be recovered. To have separate key pairs for each user, you much create each linux system users and store their public keys inside `/[user-home]/.ssh/authorized_keys` . Have a look at [this](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/managing-users.html) for reference.

Comment: Minor clarification: AWS keeps a copy of part of the key pair, namely the public key.

Comment: Yes @jarmod , Amazon keeps the public key inside ~/.ssh/authorized_keys for linux instances.

Comment: also you can get the public part of an existing key pair with the aws cli: aws ec2 describe-key-pairs --key-names yourkeyname --include-public-key

Answer (score 1):

The other person can give you a copy of the key.  It depends on how you want to control access to the system.

You can have everyone share a single key, but if you decide to prevent someone from accessing your system in the future, you will have to reissue the key.

It depends on the size of your team and the type of project you're working on.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-key-pairs.html

Comment: I think he is asking about ssh key pair for login EC2, not IAM user/credentials.

Answer (score 1):

Key Pairs for Multiple Users

If you have several users that require access to a single instance, you can add user accounts to your instance. For more information, see Managing User Accounts on Your Linux Instance. You can create a key pair for each user, and add the public key information from each key pair to the .ssh/authorized_keys file for each user on your instance. You can then distribute the private key files to your users. That way, you do not have to distribute the same private key file that's used for the root account to multiple users.

IMHO it is bad practice to share Key Pairs. Each authorized user should have their own user account on the EC2 instance and their own key pair. The key pair used for root user access should be protected and not shared among users.

[EC2 Key Pairs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-key-pairs.html)